# Network Manager, check if password is correct and connection is working

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, networkmanager

I am trying to make a script on a Debian that is checking the password of a said SSID and tries to connect to it for testing that the configuration is ok before disconnecting.

I tried the nmcli device wifi_connect funciton but unfortunately, after it connects or can't connect, we don't get any returned value, so we are unable to assess the success or failure.

I could also check the connection status with nmcli networking connectivity check after trying to connect but if NetworkManager fails to connect, it will auto connect to the last working network, and it would return a fully working connection but not for the correct SSID.

Do you have any idea how to check that the password of an Access Point is valid and that the device can connect to the access point directly? best would be with NetworkManager